# Automated deployment of Check Script for Nagios

Tags: deployment, automation, nagios

We currently use Ant to automate our deployment process. One of the tasks that requires carrying out when setting up a new Service is to implement monitoring for it.

This involves adding the service in one of the hosts in the Nagios configuration directory.

Has anyone attempted to implement such a thing where it is all automated? It seems that the Nagios configuration is laid out where the files are split up so that they are host based, opposed to application based.

For example:

localhost.cfg

This may cause an issue with implementing an automated solution as when I'm setting up the monitoring as I'm deploying the application to the environment (i.e - host). It's like a jigsaw puzzle where two pieces don't quite fit together. Any suggestions?

Ok, you can say that really you may only need to carry out the setting up of the monitor only once but I want the developers to have the power to update the checking script when the testing criteria changes without too much involvement from Operations.

Anyone have any comments on this?

Kind Regards,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

The splitting of Nagios configuration files is optional, you can have it all in one file if you want to or split it up into several files as you see fit. The [cfg_dir](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/configmain.html#cfg_dir) configuration statement can be used to have Nagios pick up any `.cfg` files found.

When configuration files have changed, you'll have to reload the configuration in Nagios. This can be done via the [external commands](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/extcommands.html) pipe.

Nagios provides a [configuration validation tool](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/verifyconfig.html), so that you can verify that your new configuration is ok before loading it into the live environment.